# Finding by Object in Doctrine : FindBy( Object )

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Is it possible to pass an object in a function such as findBy function to retrieve data?

**Note: ** The $resto object does not have the **id** attribute filled in. 
Thus doctrine has to find the closest matching entry.

For example:

```
       $resto = new Restaurant();
       $resto->setName('...')
       ...


       $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LesDataBundle:Restaurants');
       $result =  $repository->findBy($resto);
```

Comment: Define 'closest matching entry' please. Also, you cannot retrieve your `$resto` from the database unless you `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($resto)` and `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush()` it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use custom expression

```
$repository->findBy([
    'some_field' => $resto->getSomeField(),
    'other_field' => $resto->getOtherField()
]);
```